# Adding Hidden Parameters in Looker Studio Community Connector

Tags: looker-studio

I'm currently working on developing a Looker Studio Community Connector to enable users to access their data stored in our database.

The connector has many overridable config parameters, which serve to modify the data returned while keeping the data schema the same.

My objective is to assign default values to these overridable configuration parameters and, at the same time, hide them from the configuration page to maintain a cleaner and less cluttered interface.

This approach allows users to change these parameter values directly within the report, rather than within the data source's configuration settings.

These parameters play a crucial role in making API calls within my community connector to retrieve data. So I should be able to access them in my community connector code.

I tried searching the community connector documentation but could not find a way to achieve this.